# File/Command not found while running "hadoop version" command. Hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04

I'm following Micheal Noll tutorial for installing hadoop.
I followed every step as it is.
But while executing "hadoop version" command in root, I get two errors :

```
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/bin/hadoop:
line 26:     
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/bin/../libexec/hadoop- config.sh: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/bin/hadoop: 
line 133:
exec: : not found
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I found the solution to the problem. I was working on Hadoop 2.x version instead of 1.2 or other stable versions. As I re-installed the stable version, it started working without any errors.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have correct environment variable pointing to HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR

Add it to ~/.bashrc

```
export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/libexec
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the bin/hadoop path :

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$JAVA_PATH/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

But there is also other environment variable to set :

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=${HADOOP_PREFIX}/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_PREFIX/lib/native"
```

Comment: Hello. I have set hadoop home and bin variables and also added other variables as you suggested but it is still showing the same error.

Comment: Yes. I would like to provide you additional information : I have set the paths in the root's bashrc file. I installed Hadoop in root user and made Hadoop user it's owner. The java path is - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64

Comment: it's an environment PATH error. Your system is trying to find the command in your PATH but can't find it. Maybe some script is changing your PATH. (.bashrc or .profile)